# Multiple line transitions in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add another line to the line graph at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1642874.

The code is

```
var n = 40,
    random = d3.randomNormal(0, .2),
    data = d3.range(n).map(random);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

g.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
  .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .on("start", tick);

function tick() {

  // Push a new data point onto the back.
  data.push(random());

  // Redraw the line.
  d3.select(this)
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null);

  // Slide it to the left.
  d3.active(this)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
    .transition()
      .on("start", tick);

  // Pop the old data point off the front.
  data.shift();

}
```

I have basically just tried creating another dataset with `data2 = d3.range(n).map(random);` and added a line for the new dataset (using same code as in the original code, but changed the dataset variable name)

```
g.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data2)
    .attr("class", "line")
  .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .on("start", tick);
```

It does add another line with other random points, but the animation is not smooth any longer.

I don't know what makes the animation smooth.

I get the same problem with the original code if I change `n - 1` to `n`, i.e. changing

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range([0, width]);
```

to

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, n])
    .range([0, width]);
```

I cannot see why this changes the smoothness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In the tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) mentioned in your linked gist, Mike Bostock explains why that should be the domain:

> When a new data point arrives, we redraw the line instantaneously and remove the previous transform (if any). The new data point is thus initially invisible off the right edge of the chart. Then, we animate the x-offset of the path element from 0 to some negative value, causing it to slide left.

A little below, he adds:

> If you’re using spline interpolation for the path data, then note that adding a control data point changes the tangents of the previous control point, and thus the shape of the associated segments. To avoid another wiggle when the control points are changed, further restrict the visible region (the x-domain) so that the extra control point is hidden.

And you'll notice that [in the next gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1642989), Mike Bostock writes:

> When transitioning a transform on a path using basis interpolation, you must clip the path by two additional control points so that the change in tangent is not visible while the path slides left.

And that the x scale is created as follows:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, n - 2])
    .range([0, width]);
```

Since the domain only goes to `n-2`, then the `n-1` and `n` points are hidden from view (due to the `clipPath`).

Comment: Could you please show in a jsfiddle what you've tried?

Comment: It actually works at https://jsfiddle.net/j6zj9wf7/ but it seems stupid not to use the same function `tick` for both lines. How can I make the code clean?

Comment: Most functions that you pass to d3 methods receive the datum as the first parameter. In this case, when the function `tick` is called, it receives the data associated with a given `line`. The solution is to use that parameter instead of the hardcoded arrays `data1` and `data2`. This is how you can reuse the `tick` function: https://jsfiddle.net/j6zj9wf7/2/